# How do I fix the a database platform service Error when importing bacpac to Azure

Tags: azure, sqlpackage, bacpac

I received a bacpac that was created from a SQL Server 2017 (not Azure) but I want to restore it in Azure.  I tried using SSMS 2016 and connected to Azure SQL and used the Import Data Tier Application and used the bacpac stored on the local server (where I was logged on).  I got the following error:

```
Could not import package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Internal Error. The database platform service with type
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. 
You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid 
database platform service. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)
```

Do I need to install SQLPackage on the server? (It's a Windows 2012R2 server) and use that? Or should I try something different?  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql140DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid.

As you mentioned your .bacpac is create with SQL version 17 and you are trying to import it with SSMS version 16. the higher version will support lower version of bacpac, but lower version will not support will higher version of .bacpac.

Please install the latest version on SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16) it will resolve the issue.

you can also see this [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/bacpac-could-not-load-schema-model-from-package/ba-p/368765) Microsoft here they got same error for v 12 version they are trying to import with SSMS version 12